# RoleSessionName when fetching CognitoIdentityCredentials

Tags: typescript, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to embed Quicksight dashboards, in an application using a Cognito User Pool for authentication.  In order to get a url for an embedded dashboard, I allow the user to assume an IAM role that maps to a Quicksight user (automatically created) via a Cognito Identity Pool.

To allow this flow to happen, the assumed-role should have a RoleSessionName that matches a SessionName passed in to the `registerUser()` call on the Quicksight API (i.e. in this case, an email address)

My issue is that when I get credentials from the Identity Pool, passing a `RoleSessionName` in the parameters, the assumed role does not appear to have that session name set, so the call to Quicksight then fails.

Example:

```
AWS.config.credentials = new CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            IdentityPoolId: 'eu-central-1:ea3b7c31-bf53-4a30-9bdc-xxxxxxxxx',
            RoleSessionName: user.email,
            Logins: {
                'cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_xxxxxxxx' : user.id_token
            }
        })

AWS.config.getCredentials((e) => {
   let sts = new STS();
   console.log(await sts.getCallerIdentity().promise());
})
```

The result from this shows

```
{ ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'e77ea0e7-30b9-11ea-a070-e5aa4c17e68c' },
  UserId: 'AROA6JSEZRBBBBBBBB:CognitoIdentityCredentials',
  Account: '9826XXXXXXXXX',
  Arn:
   'arn:aws:sts::9826XXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/Cognito_quicksightAuth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials' }
```

My understanding is that the RoleSessionName ought to be the last part of the ARN. Compare if I assume the role directly:

```
➜  aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::9826XXXXXXXX:role/Cognito_quicksightAuth_Role --role-session-name me@mydomain.io
{
    "Credentials": {
        ...
    },
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROA6JSEZBBBBBBB:me@mydomain.io",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::9826XXXXXXXX:assumed-role/Cognito_quicksightAuth_Role/me@mydomain.io"
    }
}
```

I can show that the `RoleSessionName` is the issue in my flow, because I can make everything work by either a) creating a Quicksight user that has `CognitoIdentityCredentials` as the `SessionName`, **or** b) Explicitly assuming the role with the `RoleSessionName` through `sts.assumeRole()`

Am I wrong to expect that the call to `AWS.config.getCredentials()` would return a user with the passed `RoleSessionName` in the ARN?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is yes. You are correct with the mentioned role-base use case. The comprehensive answer is as following.

The registerUser() API allows customer to create two types of user, role-base (--session-name) or galaxy-user (--user-name). The QuickSight user ARN are

**role-base-user**

```
arn:aws:quicksight:[region]:9826XXXXXXXX:user/[namespace]/[assumed-role-name]/[session-name]
```

**galaxy-user**

```
arn:aws:quicksight:[region]:9826XXXXXXXX:user/[namespace]/[user-name]
```

Use 'default' as namespace unless your account contains other namespace. Most account's region is 'us-east-1'.

Once you have the user, you can invoke GetDashboardEmbedUrl() API to retrieve the URL for a specific user. To do so, you can provide the --user-arn argument.

```
aws quicksight get-dashboard-embed-url --user-arn "arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:9826XXXXXXXX:user/..." ...
```

If --user-arn argument is not provided, the API will generates the role-base userARN from the caller's role-name and session-name. The call will fail if the userARN does not exist in the QuickSight account. That is what you are experiencing. I recommend the use of '--user-arn' argument for deterministic behavior.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this is slightly different to what I was looking for.  The documentation states that the use of the `--user-arn` is for referencing Quicksight (not IAM) users.   Really I guess my question was more about the result of using the `CognitoIdentityCredentials` and why the resultant role doesn't include the `RoleSessionName`?  If that bit worked as I expected it to, I would expect the Quicksight lookup to work as well

Comment: @RevBingo Did you figure this out?

Comment: @BikalNepal afraid not.  My workaround was to use the CognitoIdentityCredentials to call sts.assumeRole(), which does seem to honour the RoleSessionName, and then use the resulting credentials to access Quicksight.  It works fine, just seems unnecessary.